# Dynamic Row determination from sharepoint list in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, power-platform

I am very new to powerapps and sharepoint. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a table RWB(Region Wise Budget) Available defined in sharepoint list as shown in the following screenshot.

[sharepoint table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUmeT.png)

I want to know, how to access a cell value for a specific year and a quarter for a region in powerapps dynamically.

What i want to do is extract the available budget for the selected region (in the input form) for the current year and financial quarter use it as a validation against trip totals, before allowing the user to submit the form.
(if avlbudg>total, patch() is called)

Please refer the formula i am trying to use but am not able to work it properly.

[powerapps code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITLII.png)

"currregion" variable is recognized inside the lookup function, but it is unknown outside the function.
For context, datacardvalue264 is the value from a card in an edit form which is to be submitted by user.
This code is written in the Onselect() function of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property value dynamically via `[...]`. So for example:

```
LookUp('RWB Available', Year = curryear && Quarter = currquater)[curregion]
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i have already tried doing this, but i get an error, parenclose expected.

Comment: Yes, you have a missing `)` at the end - you need to close your `Set(...)`